# Provide Fault Method in WCF receives FaultException with no details

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, service, microservices

I have implemented an `IErrorHandler` for my service witch needs to return 403 instead o 400 in case of wrong Authorization.
This is how my `ProvideFault` method looks like:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    if (((FaultException)error).Code.SubCode.Name == "FailedAuthentication")
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription =
            "StatusCode is forced to change in order to have the correct response on authentication.";
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to write a more nicer check for the error and its status code, or how to get an authorization exception not a `FaultException` witch is more general?. I don't find it nice to check after the `FailedAuthentication` string, and in fact its authorization not authentication...

Comment: Where is the exception being raised? If you can find or create a more appropriate exception you can simply check it's type. `if(error is NotAuthorizedException notAuthed){ // raise 403 error }`

Comment: As far as I know, `FailedAuthentication` code is a SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 standard [wsse:FailedAuthentication](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

If your are using C# 6.0 and above, you can use [Exception Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#exception-filters). The example is:

```
public string Example() 
{
   try
   {
      /* Method Logic */
      return string.Empty;
   }
   catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException e) when (e.Message.Contains("400"))
   {
      return "unauthorized";
   }
}
```

In your case:

```
public string Example() 
{
   try
   {
      /* Method Logic */
      return string.Empty;
   }
   catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException e) when (e.Message.Contains("400"))
   {
      ProvideFault(e, "", e.Message);
   }
}

public void ProvideFault(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
   /* your logic according to your needs. */
}
```

Comment: My exception don t contain any info about status codes.